# XCode4 Interface Builder: How to set name of an object?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

This must be a very dumb question.
I want to load a nib with UINibExternalObjects, but before that I have to change names of objects in the nib.

> Each placeholder object you add to a nib file must have a unique name. To assign a name to an object, select the object in Xcode and open the inspector window. The Attributes pane of the inspector contains a Name field, which you use to specify the name for your placeholder object. The name you assign should be descriptive of the object’s behavior or type, but really it can be anything you want.

Unfortunately, I can't find this option in any of the inspectors. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Do you have to set them up as IBOutlets in the header file and then link them in interface builder?

Comment: No, I think this isn't it. I just added a citation from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html to be more specific

Comment: There is no name attribute.  You can set a label which is only used for convenience in xcode, or you can use a tag (an integer to indentify the object called from code with:
UILabel *label = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
where 1 is the tag, or you have to use an IBOutlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only applies to "External Objects" which you add as placeholders to the nib file. (Note that these are distinct from "Objects":

[image]

If you select the external object, then in the attributes inspector there is an "Identifier" field:

[image]

This is what is referred to in the documentation. It may have been renamed from "Name" and the documentation is out of date, or it was never right.